# Remote debugging tomcat in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I want to remote debug a application running on other windows machine from my window machine. And in doing this I am able to successfully establish connection with other machine. I put a breakpoint at some line in java code, but my debugger does not come at the breakpoint.

Does anyone have the idea , what can be the problem?

Comment: How have you established the debug connection from eclipse to the remote machine? Like this: [How to setup Java remote debugging in Eclipse](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html)?

Comment: How do you find out it has successfully established connection?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the source code in your project does not match the source used to generate the compiled classes.
Verify that you are debugging the same version in the source code and the compiled classes.